# Proving three points lie on a same line

Tags: geometry, circles, tangent-line

Given two circles $C1$ and $C2$ how do I prove that the line joining their centers will pass through the point of intersection of their internal common tangents.I tried to form a linear pair and prove this but failed again and again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Each center is of equal distance to the (common) tangent lines, so it lies on one of the angle bisectors of the angles created by the tangent lines.